# Arkhangel'skii's definition of cardinal function

Tags: general-topology, translation-request, mathematical-russian

I was searching an article written by [A. V. Arkhangel'skii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Arhangelskii) called *A theorem on Cardinality*. I found it but there is a little problem: the article is in Russian. I can't read Russian and I need the definitions in the article. Particularly, the definition of the cardinal function $\text{qL}$. Here is the definition

[image]

I really aprecciate any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could guess from my minimal Russian but [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233885992_A_Note_on_Quasi-Lindelof_Spaces) confirms it, it's the *quasi-Lindelöf number* of $X$: the minimal infinite cardinality $\tau$ such that for all closed subsets $C$ of $X$ and all open covers $\mathcal{U}$ of $C$ (so that $C \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{U}$) there is a subfamily $\mathcal{U}' \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ such that $|\mathcal{U}'| \le \tau$ and $C \subseteq \overline{\bigcup \mathcal{U}'}$.

(note that Arhangel'skij uses $[]$ for closure looking at the formula in the paper).